# How to pass entire Swift class instance to another class, while using a third party ViewController/class?

Tags: ios, reference, swift2, instance

I have a class titled `ViewController` (initial view controller) that has various properties. I am trying to pass the same unique instances of these properties onto another view controller (programmatically) while within a different third party view controller/class, and without a direct Segue that passes data from the initial ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var X:string
    var dataDelegate:DataServiceDelegate?
    var Z: [String]=[]
}
```

I want to pass the entire class instance of `ViewController` to to another class, called `ClassZ` so that the properties `X`, `dataDelegate`, and `Z` are the same across both classes.

However, the Segue to `ClassZ` is programmatically called in a third party class, known as `ClassY`. Thus, I have to be able to **reference the specific class instance of ViewController (created prior to accessing ClassY) in either ClassY or Class Z without having a direct Segue from ViewController.**

I've tried the following for ClassY, in which I first try to create a pointer to a previously-created ViewController instance, and then pass it onto ClassZ programmatically. Note that the storyboard ID for the ViewController class is `mainView`:

```
class ClassY: UIViewController 
{
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    lazy var viewControllerPointer: ViewController  = {
        return self.storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainView") as! ViewController
    }()

//code goes here


    func performViewSwitchToClassZ(){
        let ClassZ:ClassZ = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainStoryBoard") as! ClassZ

        ClassZ.x=channelNumber
        ClassZ.viewController = viewControllerPointer
        presentViewController(ClassZ, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

However, when the segue to ClassZ is called and ClassZ loads, it ends up **creating a new instance of ViewController (which is "viewControllerPointer" as referenced in ClassY)**. This is a problem, because I want to be using the same instance of ViewController so that both ViewController and ClassZ end up modifying the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the right way of doing but I hope it may solve your problem, create another class with a static instance of variable viewController as follows:

```
import UIKit

class DataStore {
 static var controller: UIViewController?
 }
```

then store the instance of viewController in controller variable as follows in ViewController class:

```
 DataStore.controller = self
```

later in class Z you can access the view controller instance as follows:

```
DataStore.controller
```

Comment: Thanks Ajinkya. This definitely does work, but like you are saying I'm not sure this follows best programming practices....its basically like creating a global variable. But its a great solution for now!

Comment: yes but if you are done using the instance then you can set it to nil afterwards